# How to find a control from tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms

IDE: VS 2010, c# .net 4.0, winforms

I have a Form form1, and it is having panels  p1 p2 p3, having assigned tooltipText "pan1", "pan2", "pan3" respectively.

I know we can search control in a form using

```
Control[] c= this.controls.find("p1", true);
```

But Is there any way to find control from toolTip text,

```
//example Control[] c1 = this.control.findByToolTip("toolTipText",true);
```

I know we can map this using switch case but is there any easier way..?

Comment: this is a very horrible way of doing something like this. Cant you save the panels in a variable or something?

Comment: because I will be getting back from database tooltip text, otherwise I need to store control name in database or write a switch case to getControlNameByToolTipText(string panelName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for panel by tooltip, it is a signal that something is designed wrong in your application... but however here is how to do it

```
  var c = this.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(p => toolTipHCP.GetToolTip(p) == "toolTipText");
```

Comment: this seems a good way, Can you suggest, what if I am having different type of controls such as Panel, PitcureBox etc., then How to handle that situation, you code is just for Panel

Comment: use Control instead of Panel, OfType filters by type

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a collection of all the tooltip controls.
2. Search in this collection.

Looping through all the controls and trying to typecast each of them would be a horrible solution.

Also, your design is probably flawed. I can't think of many scenarios where identifying a control by its contents is justified. It's usually the other way around.

Comment: this strategy will be same as writing function getControlNameByToolTipText(string panelName), Is there any other inbuilt way?